# Backbone.View.remove in a Marionette application

Tags: marionette

To destroy a Backbone view, you would call its `remove` method, but in a Marionette application, the views provide a new `destroy` method which does the same, but also takes care of removing child views. Does this mean the `remove` method should never be used on Marionette views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/view.js#L152), we can see that Marionette view `destroy()` method internally calls Backbone `remove()` method. Calling `remove()` will delete the dom element and unbind events, but Marionette `destroy()` is more powerful and does a lot more plumbing, like destroying behaviors and etc. So in Marionette apps you should only use `destroy()`.

```
  destroy: function() {
    if (this.isDestroyed) { return this; }

    var args = _.toArray(arguments);

    this.triggerMethod.apply(this, ['before:destroy'].concat(args));

    // mark as destroyed before doing the actual destroy, to
    // prevent infinite loops within "destroy" event handlers
    // that are trying to destroy other views
    this.isDestroyed = true;
    this.triggerMethod.apply(this, ['destroy'].concat(args));

    // unbind UI elements
    this.unbindUIElements();

    this.isRendered = false;

    // remove the view from the DOM
    this.remove();

    // Call destroy on each behavior after
    // destroying the view.
    // This unbinds event listeners
    // that behaviors have registered for.
    _.invoke(this._behaviors, 'destroy', args);

    return this;
  },
```